# python 3 jupyter notebook - plot a candle stick chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end   = datetime(2019, 12, 15)

dox = web.DataReader('DOX', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

dox is

[image]

saw this - https://plot.ly/python/candlestick-charts/
but it only runs on python code and creates an HTML website, not as a jupyter output

here is desired output (for example)
[image]